# Android onTouch event

Tags: android

I have manage to create this code to slide in or out a button in a listview. It works ok if my gesture on the phone screen is horizontal. But if my gesture is also diagonal ... it does not trigger to show/hide the button.  The gesture is horizontal ( left to right or right to left ) but it can be a little diagonal. What to do ?

class show implements OnTouchListener
     {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                action_down_x = (int) event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                action_up_x = (int) event.getX();
                difference = action_down_x - action_up_x;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (difference < -30)
                {
                    Animation slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.slide_stanga);
                    LinearLayout right = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.dreapta);
                    if (right.isShown())
                    {
                    right.startAnimation(slide_up);
                    right.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final View x = v;
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            LinearLayout left = (LinearLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.stanga);
                            left.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(float) 4.0));
                        }
                    }, 500);

                    }

                }
                if (difference > 30)
                {
                     Animation slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.slide_dreapta);
                     LinearLayout right = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.dreapta);
                     if (!right.isShown())
                        { 
                         LinearLayout left = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.stanga);
                         left.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(float) 3.0));
                         right.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(float) 1.0));
                         right.startAnimation(slide_up);
                         right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                }
                action_down_x = 0;
                action_up_x = 0;
                difference = 0;
                break;
            }
            return true;
    }
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inbuilt option to do this. I think you should use Gesture Detector. Get the initial and final co-ordinates of the screen and then code it your way.